# How to convert $(0.11001100...)_2$ to a decimal number

Tags: arithmetic, boolean-algebra

I managed to find and understand algorithm for converting any $x \in \Bbb R$ from a decimal number to binary number.

But I have a hard time finding an algorithm for converting a binary number with infinite bits to a decimal number.
I will like to convert $(0.11001100...)_2$ to a decimal number.

Comment: How is *converting from base $b$ to base $a$* different from *converting from base $a$ to base $b$*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical formula for proper fraction is
$$(0.a_{-1}a_{-2}a_{-3}\cdots)_2 = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{-k}}{2^k}\right)_{10}$$
Where for $a_{-k}$ we have $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_{-k}\in \{ 0,1\}$.  As you see for indexing is taken negative numbers.

In your example
$$(0.11001100...)_2 =\left( \frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^6}+ \cdots\right)_{10}$$

Comment: Thanks! I just find this myself, and know someone else confirmed that my findings are correct :-).

Comment: Your formula suggests to treat binary numbers as decimal. The base inside Sigma and example should be base: 2, not base 10

Comment: @Evil. In sigma in right side and in example it is correct base - It should be $10$, but denominators was in mistake, they should be $2$s powers. I corrected, thanks for alarm.

Comment: IMO you should remove the $()_{10}$ from the RHS of your equations, because it is not surrounding a $k$-ary number representation. There is no possible confusion if you leave it out, and IMO putting it in shows a confusion about what $()_{10}$ means and when it's appropriate. The only possible confusion that could be remedied is $2^k \to (2_{10})^k$ although I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: @orlp. I do not understand what mean "IMO". $()_{10}$ in rhs means, that operations and numbers is understanding in $10$ base system. As to symbol $(2_{10})^k$, then what it mean? $2$ in base 10 in power $k$? More appropriate seems $(2^k)_{10}$.

Comment: @zkutch "IMO" stands for In My Opinion. And the subscript $b$ only makes sense when applied to a string of numbers, indicating that string should be interpreted as a base-$b$ number. The expressions on the right-hand side are not strings of numbers.

Comment: @orlp. If under "strings of numbers" you mean rhs of 2 equations in my answer, then they are exactly numbers and operations in base $10$. Sometimes it is omitting, but in this answer I prefer to emphasize base/radix for both sides.

Comment: @Xenusi But don't follow (for rational numbers) the standard order of operations as implied by the expression in the right-hand side. Instead, evaluate the right-hand side according to [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: @plop Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=0.11001100...$. in base $2$. Then $16x=1100.\overline{1100}\implies 15x=12\implies x=4/5$.

Comment: That is a very clever way

Comment: Thanks @Xenusi It's a standard trick.